# Java throws an UnsupportedDataTypeException when running OSGi with javax.mail

Tags: java, osgi

I am using OSGi and send email with javax.mail.

When I run it, it shows the following error:

> javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;

On a web forum someone claims this to be due to JDK problems.

What is the problem here?

Comment: when i using normal test.it is ok. it went wrong in the osgi framework.we are using eclipse equinox.thanks

Comment: osgi and send email with javax.mail. Perhaps you should state which versions you are running.

Comment: i tried  state versions,but it does not work for me.

Comment: ok. thats fine. a very warm welcome to stackoverflow!~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be fixed in JavaMail 1.4.4 (also try artefacts from the spring OSGi repository).

It's because javax.activiation can't see the content handlers specified by javax.mail in META-INF/mailcap

See this http://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/javamail-in-osgi/

I can't remember how I solved this before, it was a bit of hack, something like adding the javamail jar to the framework boot and adding it's exports to org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra

Comment: i found it is too complicit. i will do it in an another way.just not put  the email functionality in osgi bundle.it is like a nightmare when using javamail with osgi.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and managed to fix it by combining more than one solution:

1. Add to the MANIFEST.MF: `Require-Bundle:
   com.springsource.javax.mail;bundle-version="1.4.1"`
2. Add to the source:

`Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());`

`MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap)CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();` `mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;;x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed;x-java-fallback-entry=true");`

`CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);`